# PowerShell script to export Array in CSV format with Headers

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I've below PS Script which connects to API and puts responses on an Array List.
I'm struggling to convert Array List to CSV file and giving them a Column Header.
Anyone got Idea how to this can be done on PowerShell?

````
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $access_token")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method GET -Headers $headers -DisableKeepAlive -Certificate $certx
$js1 = $response.workers.person.legalName.givenName| ConvertTo-Json -depth 1 
$js2 = $response.workers.person.legalName.familyName1| ConvertTo-Json -depth 1
$js3 = $response.workers.businessCommunication.emails.emailUri| ConvertTo-Json -depth 1 



@($js1;$js2;$js3) | Out-File "C:\Users\file2.json"  ```

Output of above script is as below
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
]
[
    "d",
    "e",
    "f"
]
[
    "g",
    "h",
    "i"
]
````

However i would like to have output something like below.

[image: CSV File]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like combining the different property values into a single object should do the trick:

```
$response.workers | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name    = $_.person.legalName.givenName
        Surname = $_.person.legalName.familyName1
        Email   = $_.businessCommunication.emails.emailUri
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

For each desired row in the resulting CSV, construct a single object with property names corresponding to your column names - you can use `Select-Object` with [calculated property expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) to create new objects with a given "shape":

```
$outputObjects = $response.workers |Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_.person.legalName.givenName}},@{Name='Surname';Expression={$_.person.legalName.familyName1}},@{Name='Email';Expression={$_.businessCommunication.emails.emailUri}}
```

Then pipe to `Export-Csv` to create a CSV file based on the data:

```
$outputObjects |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```